# How to adjust rows into columns in django?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have made a loop in `index.html` and the pics which I added in views.html, whenever I run the code, all the pics appear in rows. I want it to be appear in columns. How could I do that?

```
views.py
    def index(request):
    dest1 = Destination()
    dest1.desc = 'Hello, How are you?'
    dest1.img = '01.jpg'

    dest2 = Destination()
    dest2.desc = 'Hello, HOw are you?'
    dest2.img = '02.jpg'

    dests1 = [dest1, dest2]
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'dests1':dests1})

  index.html
    {% static 'images/fulls' as baseUrl %}
    {% static 'images/thumbs' as hiUrl %}
    {% for dest1 in dests1 %}
    <div>
    <a href="{{baseUrl}}/{{dest1.img}}">
        <img src="{{hiUrl}}/{{dest1.img}}" alt="" />
        <h3>{{dest1.desc}}</h3>
    </a>
   </div>
    {%endfor%}
```

Comment: Will anyone answer me?

Comment: can you give example of current and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try adding this in your code:**

```
<div class="row">
{% for dest1 in dests1 %}
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <a href="{{baseUrl}}/{{dest1.img}}">
        <img src="{{hiUrl}}/{{dest1.img}}" alt="" />
        <h3>{{dest1.desc}}</h3>
    </a>
</div>
{%endfor%}
   </div>
```